# fatal error in ldap authentication code

Tags: php, ldap

Am going to avoid Login Form in my all PHP projects. Instead of Login Form am going to use LDAP Active Directory option. Automatically user can logged through Active Directory. we installed Active Directory in all systems.So all the systems are under Active Directory only.

Am using WAMP server for my PHP projects. I have enabled LDAP on my WAMP. and I have code for this Login. If I run the program means i got a error like

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE) in D:\wamp\www\ldap_connect\LdapAuth.inc.php on line 3 .

Here below the code for LDAP Authentication:

```
/* Configuration section: */
    private $serviceUser="cn=Administrator,ou=Plants,dc=vrv,dc=it";
    private $serviceSecret="serviceUSERpassword";
    /* Tip: a service user is required (keeping enabled anonymous access is a bad thing)
     * and you are supposed do write some ACL to limit the service user to read-only the cn 
     * and the uid attribute in the People tree 
     */
    private $BaseDn="ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=com"; //where are the users in the tree?
    private $UIDAttributeName="uid"; // what attribute you wanna search for the search & bind login?
```

//e.g. "mail" let users to login with their email address and password

```
    private $ServerList = Array(
        /* Multiple LDAP Servers: for load balancing/ HA redundancy mode, not for multi-ldap auth!!!!
         *  (Server MUST have some user tree synchronization mechanism e.g. OpenLDAP syncrepl ) */
        Array(
                                    "ip"=>"123.123.123.123",
                                    "name"=>"ldap-master",
                                    "sslport"=>636,
                                    "port"=>389
        ),
        Array(
                                    "ip"=>"ldap125.mydomain.com",
                                    "name"=>"ldap-replica",
                                    "sslport"=>636,
                                    "port"=>389
        )
        /* You can add or remove LDAP server entries (But this is not multi-ldap:
         *  servers MUST have the same user tree */
    );

    private $accessLogFile="ldap.access.log"; //file where access will be logged

    /* Optional parametes (keep it to empty or wrong string if you don't want AuhtZ attributes: */

     /*
      * Note: all attribute names MUST be written in lowercase e.g. givenName -> givenname
      */

    /* Optional*/ private $AuthorizativeAttrName="member";  //can be multi-value
    /* Optional*/ private $AuthorizativeJSONAttrName="x-garr-authoritativejsondata";  //single valued JSON String attribute  e.g. {"myappLevel":"admin","yourappLevel":"guest"}

    /*
     * Other configuration options can be set programmatically, check
     * for the setters methods of this class and call it before
     * calling the method authenticate() into a page to protect.
     */
```

Comment: why it showing fatal error on private line?

Comment: no one is there? to give reply?